# Сделать глубоковложенный список плоским без ветвления и циклов

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, list

Доброго времени суток всем.

Есть список:

```
lst = [1, [2, 3], 4, [[6, 7]]]
```

Его нужно привести к такому виду:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

При этом нельзя использовать ветвления и циклы, только стандартные методы. Задачка простая, но взорвала мой мозг, может более опытные товарищи помогут?

Использую Python 3.5

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2158395/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 14):

Для начала, вот версия, которая использует ветвления и циклы, чтобы было ясно ожидаемое поведение:

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten_gen(nested, isatom=lambda x: not isinstance(x, Iterable)):
    for item in nested:
        if isatom(item):
            yield item
        else:
            yield from flatten_gen(item)
```

Пример:

```
lst = [1, [2, 3], 4, [[6, 7]]]
print(list(flatten_gen(lst)))
# -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

где `isatom()` предикат определяет что является атомом (неразрывным объектом) с точки зрения этого метода. Подразумевается, что "не атомы" можно в цикл передать, чтобы получить объекты, из которых они состоят.

Алгоритм прямолинейный: перебирая элементы переданного списка, отдаём атомы как есть, а для составных объектов, вызываем генератор рекурсивно.

Так как строки по умолчанию работают с циклами, то если вы хотите их рассматривать как атомы в вашем случае, то передайте `isatom` явно:

```
isatom = lambda x: isinstance(x, str) or not instance(x, Iterable)
```

Если только целые числа считаются атомами, то `isatom = lambda x: isinstance(x, int)`.

---

Рекурсивная версия без явного ветвления, циклов, используя [iterable unpacking синтакс](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#rationale):

```
def flatten(nested):
    try:
        first, *rest = nested
    except TypeError: # not an iterable
        return [nested]
    except ValueError: # empty
        return []
    return flatten(first) + flatten(rest)
```

Код отпиливает первый элемент от заданного вложенного списка и соединяет плоский список, полученный из него с помощью рекурсивного вызова `flatten(first)`, с плоским списком, полученным вызовом с остатком входного списка `flatten(rest)`.

Если не получается отпилить первый элемент из-за того, что ввод пустой или скаляр дан (не перечислимое значение—число к примеру), то возвращается пустой список или этот скаляр внутри списка соответственно.

Если на входе вложенный список с числами, то на каждом уровне задача уменьшается до тех пор пока функция не будет вызвана с простейшими параметрами: число или пустой список, что приводит к возвращению конкретных значений и собиранию конечного результата при подъёме по стеку вызовов.

Данная реализация не работает со строками без адаптации, так как `'a' == 'a'[0]` (строка из одного символа равна своему первому символу)—это приводит к бесконечной рекурсии в данном случае.

Код не оптимален по производительности (для простоты), но нет if/else ветвлений и циклов.

---

Вот похожая, но более эффективная версия, которая использует генератор:

```
def flatten_gen(nested):
    try:
        it = iter(nested)
    except TypeError: # not an iterable
        yield nested
        return
    try:
        first = next(it)
    except StopIteration: # empty
        return
    yield from flatten_gen(first)
    yield from flatten_gen(it)
```

Генератор пытается получить итератор `it` с помощью `iter(nested)` и если на входе скаляр (например, целое число), то выбрасывается `TypeError` и генератор возвращает этот скаляр (`yield`). `next(it)` возвращает первый элемент из итератора, если он не пустой. Затем рекурсивно генерируются скаляры для первого элемента и оставшихся элементов в `it` итераторе.

---

Если можно использовать циклы из библиотечного кода, наподобие `sum(map(flatten, lst, []))` решения из [@borisrozumnuk ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584610/23044), то можно улучшить `flatten_gen()` генератор, используя [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

def flatten_gen(nested):
    try:
        it = iter(nested)
    except TypeError:  # not an iterable
        yield nested
    else:
        yield from chain.from_iterable(map(flatten_gen, it))
```

Так как рекурсия не используется в этом случае, чтобы цикл реализовать, то количество вызовов вдвое меньше.

---

Если хочется, можно в виде одного выражения записать:

```
def flatten(nested):
    return (isinstance(nested, int) and [nested] # an int
            or nested # empty
            and flatten(nested[0]) + flatten(nested[1:])) # non-empty list
```

Что работает, благодаря short-circuit поведению and/or логических операторов. Не ясно рассматривать ли это как использование ветвления.

Если `nested` это целое, то код возвращает это число, обёрнутое в список (`[nested]`). Если `nested` не целое число (а список), то он сразу возвращается, если он пустой (`len(nested) == 0` означает, что `bool(nested) is False`). Если `nested` не пустой список, то возвращается объединение плоских списков, возвращаемое рекурсивными вызовами для первого элемента и остатка от списка—также как и в решениях выше в этом ответе.

---

Если двигаться дальше в сторону нечитаемости кода, то ветвление можно заменить с помощью индексирования списков и `lambda`, чтобы задержать выполнение:

```
def flatten(nested):
    return [
        lambda: [        # list (not an int)
              lambda: flatten(nested[0]) + flatten(nested[1:]),  # non-empty list
              lambda: []                                         # empty
    ][not nested](),
        lambda: [nested] # an int
    ][isinstance(nested, int)]()
```

Общая идея: `True == 1 and False == 0` в Питоне, поэтому выражение `[on_false, on_true][condition]()` вызывает `on_false` функцию, если `condition` ложно и `on_true`—если истинно.

Answer (score 11):

just for fun =)

```
flatten = lambda lst :eval('['+str(lst).replace('[','').replace(']','')+']')
flat_list = flatten(lst)
```

Но лучше не использовать `eval()` в вашем коде, подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

---

Ну или так (можно указать несколько типов):

```
flatten = lambda lst: isinstance(lst, (int, str, float, bool)) and [lst] or sum(map(flatten, lst), [])
lst = ["a", [2.3, True], 'abc', [[6, 7]]]
flat_list = flatten(lst)
print(flat_list)
['a', 2.3, True, 'abc', 6, 7]
```

Comment: Можно ast.literal_eval вместо eval здесь использовать.

Comment: Стоит явно упомянуть, что даже по супер низким стандартам решений, которым нельзя использовать "ветвление и циклы", *манипуляция кода как простой строки совмещённое с `eval()` является грязным грязным хаком* (после использования частные места могут отвалится)—вы предупреждены.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [1, [2, 3], 4, [[6, 7]]]
q = str(lst)
a = q.replace("[",'')
b = a.replace("]",'')
g = b.replace(",",'')
y = g.replace(" ",'')
s = list(map(int, list( y )))
print (s)
```

Посоветовал старший товарищ. Этот код не будет работать, если в изначальном массиве будут строки, числа и булевые значения, но для конкретного примера он сработает. 
Ответы senior-zero и jfs - лучшие (ИМХО).

Comment: [Мой комментарий к другому ответу тут также применим](http://goo.gl/OuWqUa). Если вы хотите со строками работать и вас интересуют только целые числа, то можно упростить решение: `list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', str(lst))))`

Comment: Что-то сомнительный ответ. Тут же даже с числами, в которых больше одной цифры, работать не будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy верно, хотя `g.split()`, вместо `g.replace(" ", '')` легко снимет это ограничение. (Если оставить в стороне сам факт, разумности с кодом как с простой строкой без структуры работать).

Comment: минусовать ответ не нужно—код работает для примера из вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходим рекурсивный обход элементов списка. К примеру:

```
lst = [1, [2, 3], 4, [[6, 7]]]

def lst_to_flat(S):
   if S == []:
      return S
   if isinstance(S[0], list):
      return lst_to_flat(S[0]) + lst_to_flat(S[1:])
   return S[:1] + lst_to_flat(S[1:])

print(lst_to_flat(lst))
```

Comment: Автор же написал, что ветвления нельзя использовать.

Comment: `if S == []:` вот так лучше не делать, гораздо "питонячее" так: `if not S`

Answer (score 0):

```
def normalize(item):
    return flatten(item) if isinstance(item, list) else [item]

def flatten(tree):
    return sum(map(normalize, tree), [])
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
# numpy - быстро и хорошо
# конкретно для данного случая не годится, ну или годится с изменениями
# длины членов массива должны совпадать, 
# а чаще всего так и бывает

import numpy as np
lst_np = np.array(lst)
lst_r = list(lst_np.ravel())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: "конкретно для данного случая не годится, ну или годится с изменениями"... зачем, в таком случае, публиковать это в качестве ответа?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def flatten(lst):
    return sum(map(flatten, lst), []) if isinstance(lst, list) else [lst]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]