# Сумма элементов многомерного списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал такой код:

```
def S(a):
  return lambda a: a if type(a) is int else [S(b) for b in a].sum

L = [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8]]
print(S(L))
```

Но не работает. В чем ошибка? P. S. У меня еще был такой вариант:

```
def Sum(a):
  if type(a) is int:
    return a
  else:
    result = 0
    for b in a:
      result += Sum(b)
    return result
```

Но я хотел бы что бы и первый заработал. Как исправить первый вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, который "плющит" списки и кортежи любого уровня вложенности:

```
from collections import abc

def flatten(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, (str, bytes)):
            yield item
        elif isinstance(item, abc.Sequence):
            yield from flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item


L = [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8]]
print(sum(flatten(L)))
```

Или ваш исправленный вариант:

```
def S(a):
    return a if type(a) is int else sum([S(b) for b in a])


L = [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8]]
print(S(L))
```

Comment: Непонятен вариант с yield.

Comment: Не знакомы с генераторами?

Comment: Знаком с генераторами списков.

Comment: Не совсем то. Генераторы - это, пожалуй, одна из самых полезных частей python, обеспечивающая ленивые последовательности и асинхронность. В общих чертах ознакомится можно [здесь](https://lancelote.gitbooks.io/intermediate-python/content/book/generators.html). Но я бы советовал поискать главы учебников, посвящённые этой теме, и погуглить дополнительные статьи. У Дэвида Бизли [есть интереснейшие и очень доходчивые презентации](http://www.dabeaz.com/tutorials.html) на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Есть один очень грязный хак, но так делать категорически не советую:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: L = [[1, 2], 3, [4, [5, 6]], 7, [8]]

In [3]: sum(map(int, re.findall('\d+', str(L))))
Out[3]: 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сплющить вложенный список и суммировать числа:

```
>>> sum(flatten_gen(L))
36
```

где [`flatten_gen()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584650/23044).