# Как вывести все элементы списка во вложенном списке в csv файл без знаков ( запятые, знаки списка и т д)

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Имею список со вложенными списками внутри которых есть списки. Нужно все элементы вывести в csv файл. Однако,при выводе у меня записываются также и знаки ('' , [ ).

Вот код:

```
Write = open('file_way.csv', 'w', newline='')
matrix = [['YE_005_4G',['a', 'b', '\n']], 
          ['AG_234_4G',['c','\n d','g']], 
          ['GY_076_4G',['  \n', 'z' , 'y']]]
transposed = []
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
   new_row = []
   for row in matrix:
       new_row.append(row[i])
   transposed.append(new_row)

 Write.write('\n'.join(str(value) for value in transposed))
 Write.close()
 print('ENodeBFunction parameters parsed - normal')
```

Пример моего построчного вывода в csv:

```
['YE_005_4G', ['a',  'b',  '\n']
'AG_234_4G',['c','\n d','g']
'GY_076_4G',['  \n', 'z' , 'y']]
```

Нужно вывести так (убрав все лишнее-оставив текст):

```
 YE_005_4G, a, b,   ,
 AG_234_4G, c, d,  g,
 GY_076_4G,  , z , y
```

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы `['YE_005_4G',['a', 'b', '\n']]` список превратился в `['YE_005_4G', 'a', 'b', '\n']`?

Comment: @jfs Да вы правы. Нужно чтобы каждый  вложенный список имел такую структуру.

Comment: к чему transposed здесь (`zip(*matrix)`)? Может вы хотите  первый столбец как заголовок, а вложенные списки как столбцы, а не строки рассматривать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так, только из вопроса непонятно, как вы хотите интерпретировать символы перевода строки.

```
matrix = [['YE_005_4G',['a', 'b', '\n']], 
          ['AG_234_4G',['c','\n d','g']], 
          ['GY_076_4G',['  \n', 'z' , 'y']]
          ]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    for i in matrix:
        f.write(', '.join([i[0], *i[-1]]).replace('\n', ''))
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: У вас перевод строки интерпретируется, как новая строка. Однако, нужно чтобы оно интерпретировалось, как объект списка ( чтобы оно имело пустое значение).

Comment: @DavidGrigoryev обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо! То что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы сделать плоским (flatten) возможно глубоковложенный список:

```
def flatten(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584650/23044):

```
>>> [*flatten([1, [2, 3], 4, [[6, 7]]])]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Чтобы записать как csv:

```
csv.writer(file).writerows(tuple(flatten(row)) for row in matrix)
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/Rf5GgY):

```
YE_005_4G,a,b,"
"
AG_234_4G,c,"
 d",g
GY_076_4G,"  
",z,y
```