# Как объединить подсписки в один список? (Python)

Tags: python, list

Хорошего всем дня. У меня есть cписок:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
<class 'list'>
```

Нужно получить результат:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать глубоковложенный список плоским без ветвления и циклов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584595/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё делается легко:

```
data = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6'], ['7', '8']]
result = sum(data, [])
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```